# Conditional delete and insert in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables `Table_A` and `Table_B`. How can I write a conditional SQL that does the following logic

```
If table A records match table B records on id
then
    delete records from table A and Insert records into Table B
```

How can I do this with SQL most likely using `with`

```
delete from Table_A where Exists (select a.id from TABLE_A
join TABLE_B as b on a.id = b.id)
```

The Insert is:`Insert into Table_A (id) select id from TABLE_B`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CTE to catch the ids of the deleted records, and re-join these with the b records:

```
WITH del AS (
        DELETE FROM a
        WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM b
                WHERE b.id = a.id
                )
        returning *
        )
INSERT INTO a (id, x, y, z)
SELECT id, x, y, z
FROM b
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM del
        WHERE del.id = b.id
        );
```

---

BTW: you should have **very good reasons** (such as wanting to activate the triggers) to prefer delete+insert to a update.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to avoid update because of the geometry complexities